# Rest WCF service returns 404

Tags: wcf, rest, iis, http-status-code-404

I develop web service using WCF and host this guy is IIS 7.5. Then generate js proxy (using

```
http://host/Site/Contracts/Service.svc/js
```

feature from browser) to call service from web page.
Everything works fine. But on the test machine IIS return 404 error when i try to call method of this service. On my machine service return correct Json. I spend few days trying to figure out where is the problem.

What can cause the problem with 404 error?

Comment: post your config file

Comment: @iamkrillin Here http://pastebin.com/qWXZPaEs

Comment: @sakir Change to what? 
Add port 59504? I already tried that. Not helped.

Answer (score 0):

Change your endpoint to use the "web" behaviorConfiguration and set the address to js

```
<endpoint address="js" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ExcelTools.Controllers.Service1" />
```